# Text-align: right doesn't work

Tags: html, css, text-align

I'm trying to make my menuitems go to the right on my menubar. But it doesn't work. It doesn't even work to get it to align left again, even when I remove the align: center code. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

```css
.menu {
  background-color: black;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.menuItem {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.menuItem a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menuItem a:hover {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menuItem"><a href="Quizes.aspx">Välj quiz</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem"><a href="Login.aspx">Logga in</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="mainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to show the HTML.

Comment: You don't even have text-align in your CSS code.

Comment: @SleekGeek - that explains why it doesn't work :P

Comment: Given `.menuItem{display:inline}`, you can apply `.menu {text-align:right;}` to align items to the right.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like  ..... 
try this
(added text-align:right and it works fine)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .menu {
    background-color: black;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.menuItem {

    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: right;
}
.menuItem li{
    list-style: none;
     display: inline;
     color:white;
}

.menuItem a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menuItem a:hover {
    color: purple;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
    <div class="menuItem"><ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
</ul>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you change and why? A little explanation might be helpful.

Comment: i just added text-align: right; to menu item and for menu items i use unordered list

Comment: I see. That works, but what's the purpose of `div.menuItem`? I think it could be [re-organized a little](http://jsfiddle.net/z74qnrjr/). But anyway, downvoters care to comment?

Comment: i wanted to help who asked the question i dont know why they are voting in minus.